# DCPROMO on new remote Domain Controller fails because "the RPC server is unavailable"

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, domain-controller, active-directory

I'm helping a (*devops*) client move their technology stack (VMware, Windows AD, Ubuntu Linux) from their old co-location facility to a new environment. Rather than move the hardware and systems outright, I've built a parallel environment in the new data center...

One thing I need to establish in the new site is Active Directory. There's an existing AD comprised of a single domain controller at their old site (2008 R2). While the new facility has a Cisco ASA firewall, their old site does not. Their current systems are exposed to the web with no firewalling; including the domain controller! A site-to-site VPN tunnel does not seem to be an option.

I'd like to build another domain controller at the new site; basically joining a domain *over the internet*. This is necessary for the VMware Virtual Center, DNS and a few other things I need to proceed with the new environment. I built a new Windows 2008 R2 server and took the following steps:

- *Successfully* joined it to the domain (over the internet, limiting the new site to the old site's source addresses).
- Added a new AD site for the old and new subnets (they're different).
- Verified what I could of DNS.
- Installed the AD binaries.
- Ran `dcpromo` under a domain Administrator account.

The `dcpromo` step fails a few minutes into the process with:

> The operation failed because:
>
> Active Directory Domain Services could not create the NTDS Settings
>   object for this Active Directory Domain Controller CN=NTDS
>   Settings,CN=DC2,CN=Servers,CN=ServerCentral,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=hire-a-sysadmin,DC=com
>   on the remote AD DC PEDC.hire-a-sysadmin.com. Ensure the provided
>   network credentials have sufficient permissions.
>
> "The RPC server is unavailable."

I did notice that the old domain controller I'm trying to replicate from is multi-homed. Since the client does not have a firewall at their old co-location site, their servers all seem to have public IPs and default gateways that point to the web, and a second interface slated for internal communication on a 10.10.10.0/24 subnet. I could see that being an issue, as it just *seems* like a bad practice.

**How can I complete the `dcpromo` process on this new domain controller?**

Edit - I ran [Port Query](http://blogs.technet.com/b/abizerh/archive/2009/06/11/troubleshooting-rpc-server-is-unavailable-error-reported-in-failing-ad-replication-scenario.aspx), as recommended below. The only port with a non-zero status was port 42 - `TCP port 42 (nameserver service): NOT LISTENING`. I believe that's only for WINS resolution.

Comment: can you post the asa congfig?

Comment: @user1008764 No. What are you suggesting?

Comment: I'd go with the firewall blocking an important port.
Run through the steps here, it may provide clues: http://blogs.technet.com/b/abizerh/archive/2009/06/11/troubleshooting-rpc-server-is-unavailable-error-reported-in-failing-ad-replication-scenario.aspx

Comment: @JamesHebden All of **IP** is allowed on the Cisco from the source DC to the new DC.

Comment: Is there any NAT involved, or does the new DC have a public IP?

Comment: @JamesHebden The new DC has a 1:1 NAT through the Cisco ASA.

Comment: Try putting static entries in both hosts files.

Comment: @TheCleaner Static entries got me a bit further in the process... but still ended up with an RPC error.

Comment: is there a default gateway configured on the interfaces in the 10.10.10.0/24 net?

Comment: @user1008764 No. There's no default gateway on that interface.

Comment: ok. check the firewall config. do you have inspect dcrpc and/or inspect dns (if dns-> yes which size limit)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As janky as this is, I ended up establishing a Cisco client VPN from the old DC to the new datacenter's ASA firewall.  This allowed replication and the `dcpromo` to complete.

Comment: Oh, @MDMarra You made the problem worse!